# How can I change the width of container to 1400px?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to use custom container in Bootstrap 3 to 1400px. How can I count grid column width and and @grid-gutter-width?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use bootstrap SASS port you can easily do that by changing `_bootstrap-variables.scss`.

In `_bootstrap-variables.scss` search for `$container-large-desktop` and change its value to `(1370px + $grid-gutter-width)`.

Default `$grid-gutter-width` is 30 px. You can change it also.
If you change `$grid-gutter-width` then change the `$container-large-desktop` accordingly to get your container size 1400px.

To know how to work with bootstrap SASS check it out : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not familiar with SASS, any other solution.

Comment: Visit http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and search for Container sizes
and edit it according to your need.

Comment: I've made that changes in _bootstrap-variables.scss, but now how to set bootstrap in HTML with Sass.

Comment: You need to install SASS in your machine first. then you can run the your bootstrap stylesheet. If you don't have any idea about SASS then I recommend you to use getbootstrap.com/customize link  and customize your css. But you can learn SASS it's a great pre processor to work with.

Comment: might be better to add your own variables file overwriting the bootstrap variables definitions.

Comment: Hi @GolamMortuza, I have changes on the _bootstrap-variables.scss file but the changes are not reflecting. I dont know why. is there a chache on scss that i should remove?

Answer (score 33):

To change the container size from core,
you have to declare your bootstrap container variable again, if you use bootstrap scss.

```
$container-max-widths: (
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) ;
```

Comment: Should be higher!

Answer (score 10):

Better you should use Bootstrap fluid layout, like:

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid"></div>
</div>
```

You can checkout this page to know more about Bootstrap fluid layout - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-fluid-layout.php

Comment: Thanks, but i don't want to use container fluid, i'm still beginner with Bootstrap.

Comment: Fluid is designed to be fullpage, container should be used for fixed max-width.

Comment: This is really bad. Why even use Bootstrap? And if you're going to do this, just make a CSS rule that container-fluid has a max width of 1400px and it does the same thing without adding extra HTML everywhere.

Comment: I dont like container-fluid coz im one of those people with 21in+ iMac screen. The site look weird and logo would appear on far left not right infront of your eyes.

Comment: Use max-width instead of width so it's still responsive

Answer (score 5):

Best and simplest solution I found myself:

You use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container` and add `@media` request in CSS with `min-width` little bit higher than required:

```
@media (min-width: 1405px) {
  .container-fluid{
    width: 1400px;
  }
}
```

And enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Under bootstrap version 4 using sass:

```
$container-max-widths: (
  xl: 1200px
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the container width on the Bootstrap customise page at:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Under Container Sizes change @container-large-desktop to your desired size. Remember to take into account the gutters.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way I found is to set the .container-fluid to auto in your site.css file for custom site css settings*:

```
.container-fluid {
width: 1400px;
```

}

I prefer auto for most cases though:

```
    .container-fluid {
width: auto;
```

}

Then use the container-fluid class instead of container.

*Creating this file is a best practices for customizations you need to make for your site. This way the original css libraries remain intact and when you get an update to them, your customizations remain intact as well.